# Most effective way to perform Matrix Multiplication on Polars

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication, python-polars

Considering the example data bellow what is the correct way to perform a matrix multiplication with data that is in Polars?

```py
In []: matrix_1 = pl.DataFrame({"col_1":[1,2,3],"col_2":[4,5,6], "col_3":[7,8,9]})
In []: matrix_2 = pl.DataFrame({"col_1":[9,8,7],"col_2":[6,5,4], "col_3":[3,2,1]})
```

I've done the following using numpy to perform computation:

```py
In []: np.matmul(matrix_1, matrix_2)
Out[]: 
array([[ 30,  24,  18],
       [ 84,  69,  54],
       [138, 114,  90]])

In []: np.dot(matrix_1, matrix_2)
Out[]: 
array([[ 30,  24,  18],
       [ 84,  69,  54],
       [138, 114,  90]])
```

I was just wondering if there's a native way to do it to avoid copies because IRL I'm using much more data and if I could have the ergonomy of not having to convert data in and out of numpy this would be great.

P.s.: Another great thing would be able to use the `@` to use the `__matmult__` that if I'm not mistaken is not implemented in Polars API.

Comment: Searching `matmul` on the issue tracker brings up https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/925 which seems to have stagnated. Perhaps `@` is worth a feature request. I'm not 100% sure on the exact details of your example but `np.matmul` is a `ufunc` and ufuncs are said to work with [*"almost zero overhead."*](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/interop/numpy.html)

Comment: I'll probably request the `@` feature, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The interoperability of polars with numpy is already pretty strong [as per the link @jqurious already posted in comments](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/interop/numpy.html).

You can also see that interoperability in the fact that you can even use polars dataframes as the input to `np.dot`.

It seems what you really need/want is a way to do the following while getting back a DataFrame

```
matrix_1.dot(matrix_2)

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ col_1 ┆ col_2 ┆ col_3 │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 30    ┆ 84    ┆ 138   │
│ 24    ┆ 69    ┆ 114   │
│ 18    ┆ 54    ┆ 90    │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

You can achieve this by making a helper function and then monkey patching it into `pl.DataFrame`

Just do:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
def dot(self, rightdf):
    return pl.from_numpy(np.dot(self, rightdf), columns=rightdf.columns)
pl.DataFrame.dot=dot
```

and then when you create your `matrix_1` and `matrix_2` it will have the method dot built in as above.